# DFS-Share not uptodate for SOME users

Tags: dfs

We have a DFS Share setup on 2 Servers. (2008-R2)

Today we encountered a very strange issue:

- The shares are replicated fine (both servers show the same data localy)
- For 70% of clients everything is fine, they have access on the latest data.
- about 30% of clients having a "view" that is outdated (files added during the weekend are not visible)

Any Idea how that could happen? didn't even know that file-content of DFS-Shares might be cached by the client?

Most the time, rebooting the PC in question resolves this - but we have two cases now where the latest data is not visible, even after rebooting the pcs multiple times.

Old data is perfectly fine and accessable, but some files are just not "visible" at all... ?

Win 7 and Win10 clients affected.

Comment: Do you use only DFS-R or DFS-R + DFS Namespaces?
Do you use "Offline files" in your enviroment?
Are any of affected files in "DfsrPrivate\ConflictandDeleted" folder on FileServer?

Comment: I assume the issue is related to “Offline Files” on affected clients, so please check.

Comment: P.S. DFS-R as asynchronous replication may have issues with outdated files on servers and you can benefit with it only for remote site replication over slow network channel. Clustered file server role, which is running on high available shared storage, provides with better performance (as file is read from two sources simultaneously) and better redundancy (as there are no “unsynchronized” data). An example of free Windows based high available file server - www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/part-2-smb-3-0-file-server-on-free-microsoft-hyper-v-server-2012-r2-clustered